# Find a basis for the row space, column space, kernel, and image of the following matrix verification

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, vector-spaces

For the following matrix:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
    2 & 5 & 5 & 6 \\
    3 & 7 & 6 & 11 \\
    1 & 5 & 10 & 8 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I want to find a  basis for the Row space, Column space, Kernel (if it represents a Linear Transformation), and Image(if it represents a Linear Transformation).

The row echelon form of this matrix is:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Row space basis:

$$\{(1,2,1,3),(0,1,3,0),(0,0,0,2)\}$$

Column space basis:

$$\{(1,2,3,1),(2,5,7,5),(3,6,11,8)\}$$

Kernel basis:

$x+2y+z+3w=0$

$y+3z=0$

$2w=0$

$(x,y,z,w)=z(5,-3,1,0)$

$$\{(5,-3,1,0)\}$$

Image basis (same as column space):

$$\{(1,2,3,1),(2,5,7,5),(3,6,11,8)\}$$

---

Are my above solutions correct? Of not then why?

Comment: Without checking the numerical calculations, it looks good.

Comment: You can check that you’ve gotten the correct basis for the kernel yourself by multiplying that vector by the matrix.